# why is my board not being rendered in the same orientation as the 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

With this code I'm getting the board in the picture. can any please help me figure out why this is happening and how I fix it.
I've tried calling super.paintComponent but nothing is changing. if i just needed the board I would have probably left it but I  implemented a search and the search kept going to the wrong position because the array doesnt match the board which I dont understand because the array is defining the board. This problem is beyond my abilities and help is greatly appreciated.

```
 protected int[][] board = {
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },

    };

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

   for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board[0].length ; col++) {
            Color color;
            switch (board[row][col]) {
            case 0:
                color = new Color(149, 153, 146);
                break;
            default:
                color = new Color(38, 252, 0);

            }
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fillRect(row * pixelSize, col * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);

        }
    }

}
```

[image: board]

Comment: Most likely you got switched `row` with `column` somewhere, try playing with those and see how the result changes. I'd guess that in graphics the bottom left corner got index 0,0 and for the array in Java thats top left corner

Comment: In `fillRect(x, y, width, height)`, the `x` (horizontal)  coordinate should use the value of `col`, and the `y` (vertical) coordinate the value of `row` . Just do `g2.fillRect(col * pixelSize, row * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);` .

Comment: Thank you. its the simple stuff that always cause me the most trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`g2.fillRect(row * pixelSize, col * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);`

to this:

`g2.fillRect(col * pixelSize, row * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);`

X coordinate comes before Y.

X is defined by column.
Y is defined by row.